# POST request validation on Jupyter kernel gateway

Tags: python, post, jupyter-notebook, gateway, jupyter-kernel

I'm trying to understand how to pass data via POST request method in Jupyter notebook kernel gateway and make a validation of the parameters.

I have already made some tests with GET method and It works as expected:

```
import json

# GET /get
req = json.loads(REQUEST)
args = req['args']

if 'name' not in args:
  print(json.dumps({'name': None}))
else:

  name = args['name'][0]
  print(json.dumps({'name': name}))
```

So, if I got to http://127.0.0.1:8888/get?name=John I get the desired output of the GET request in json format.

But what if I want (after the previous GET validation) also to make a POST request passing a **raw body** like this and make the correct validation in order to output the value parameters only in case they are filled or not empty/null?

```
{"parameter_1":"5",
 "parameter_2":"33",
 "parameter_3":"120"
}
```

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as making a GET request.
You add a key in the REQUEST object, 'body'

And do something like this:

```
# POST /formdata
req = json.loads(REQUEST)
body = req['body']
```

Validate it according to your business logic.

Comment: Is it possible to send images through POST?